# How to keep temporary table after running stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know the temporary table will be deleted after the connection is lost. But within that connection, I want to do something like

```
EXEC test;

SELECT * FROM #Final;
```

`#Final` is the temporary table created in the stored procedure. The stored procedure needs 30 seconds, and I want to check my `#final` without running stored procedure again.

If I run the script in that stored procedure, the `#final` can be reused in the connection. But how to use it after the `EXEC test`?

So, except for creating a real table, is it possible to `SELECT * FROM #Final` after `EXEC test`? If no, I'll use real table instead. Thanks!

Comment: Its automatically removed when you exit the SP, you need to create it before the SP for it still to exist.

Comment: Sounds like you wanted the temporary table just for debugging purposes. In this case, change to use global temp table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you don't want a temporary table.  Use either a global temporary table (`##final`) or a real table.

Then delete the results after you run the procedure.

I should note that the stored procedure can return a result set which you can insert into a table, using `exec()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use a global temporary Table

```
create proc demo as 
begin
 select * into ##temptable from original_table
end

exec demo;

select * from ##temptable
```